# What does 16#4000000 mean in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I'm reading ejabberd source, specifically `ejabberd_http.erl`.

In the code below,

```
 ...
 case (State#state.sockmod):recv(State#state.socket,
                          min(Len, 16#4000000), 300000)
 of
   {ok, Data} ->
     recv_data(State, Len - byte_size(Data), <<Acc/binary, Data/binary>>);
 ...
```

What does `16#4000000` mean?
I've tested this in the Erlang shell.

```
%%erlang shell 
...

7>16#4000000.
67108864

8>is_integer(16#4000000).
true
```

I know it's just an integer value.

Is there any advantage to writing `16#4000000` instead of `67108864`?

Comment: I think for writing 16#4000000 is more simple than 67108864. And it depends on author's favor. You can write in different base such as 2#101010 = 42, 8#0677 = 447, 16#AE = 174

Comment: read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/erlang/1128/data-types/3636/numbers)

Comment: Thanks, your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Erlang, the number before the # is the integer base. In your example, `16#4000000` means the hexadecimal representation of `67108864`. In other languages it is often represented as `0x4000000`.

One reason for using the hex representation is because each digit represents 4 bits, for example `16#F` is `16` (in decimal), or `1111` in binary. When working with binary processing, using base 16 makes it easier to handle and understand for the human reader.